# Custom Content in wall post via web app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have developed a website and I want users to be able to share their activity on facebook. I am able to post a simple message and an image using graph api, but I need to be able to post customized content, like Foursquare and other apps do. For example, when a Foursquare user shares his checkin on facebook, it shows a map and an info box which contains a few images of that place. How can I customize the content shown in the facebook post?

Comment: Has it got something to do with open graph?

Comment: look for open graph actions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/opengraph/